# Libgdx Setting TextField size does not change its size

Tags: java, libgdx, resize, scene2d

With a TextField Object I've created in Scene2D, I'm attempting to resize it so that it can fit to the size of the within the TextField.

There doesn't seem to be a way of getting the appropriate font directly from the TextField and moreover:

```
setSize(float x, float y)
```

doesn't change the size of the object whatsoever.

I've tested the other methods like setColor which seems to work, so I'm scratching my head as to why setting the size of this object doesn't work.

Thanks.

PS: This project is for Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

It will fit to the size of the cell you place it in. If you create a table and put it in a cell you can set the cell size for it.

```
table.add(myTextfield).width(xxx).height(yyy);
table.add(myTextfield).expand().fill();
```

You have to set it's font and other attributes like color, background, cursor, etc trough `TextfieldStyle` and add that to your `Textfield`. Or create a json `Skin` where you would fill out all the details of your stage actors.